# Is it possible to execute TF history command from a script build task?

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild

I am setting up new builds in TFS 2018 on premise.  We need to track the changesets used for our builds.

I have a PowerShell script as a build task that executes TF.exe history command to get the info.

This script runs as long as I execute it from my session but it fails from the build process with a "you are not authorized to access " message.  I realize I can add my login info to the command and it will work as expected.

Is there a way to specify that it run as the local system?  The user is runs under now is "machinename$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by running

```
tf /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
```

But you have to allow access to token on the build agent phase.
Edit your build definition, click on the options view. There you will find the field to allow token access.